# How to get String value from "getFirebase().auth().currentUser.getIdToken()"

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a *ReactJS* app and am using *firebase* for authentication.

I have a *NodesJS* bakend server that uses the `idToken` for authentication.

I am trying to send the `idToken` to the server using:

```
const idToken = getFirebase().auth().currentUser.getIdToken();
```

in

```
async function updateDataInDatabase(data, dispatch, getFirebase) {
    const idToken = getFirebase().auth().currentUser.getIdToken();
    console.log('Todo App: Updating data in database using idToken ', idToken);
    console.log('Todo App: Updating data in database using idToken ', idToken.i);
    try {
        await axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/app/todo/data`, JSON.stringify(data), {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'firebase-idToken': idToken },
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        return err.message;
    }
}
```

But its logged as `undefined`.

The first `console.log` gives this:

```
D {a: 0, i: undefined, c: D, b: null, f: null, …}
a: 2
b: null
c: null
f: null
g: false
h: false
i: "eyJhbGciOiJS[....]yCORe2rP5PDCvmnVBkEzqug4Qrje9DlqwUIASEM7jmBUgOHQLNKWeTpe9Yl2w"
__proto__: Object
```

Is this an `Object`?
What does the upper letter **D** stand for?

I thought the token then would be the `i` attribute, so I tried to get the `i` attribute, buy the second `console.log` gives the following as well:

```
undefined
```

How can that be?

Answer (score 2):

The *firebase* SDK documentation states the following for [the `getIdToken` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.User#getidtoken):

> getIdToken ( forceRefresh ? :  boolean ) : Promise < string > Returns
>   a JSON Web Token (JWT) used to identify the user to a Firebase
>   service.
>
> Returns the current token if it has not expired. Otherwise, this will
>   refresh the token and return a new one.
>
> Parameters Optional forceRefresh: boolean Force refresh regardless of
>   token expiration.
>
> Returns Promise

Which means the result you are getting when logging the `idToken` variable is a `Promise` object and not the token literal you had expected:

You should `await` for the `getIdToken` method return value or use the `Promise#then` style:

```js
async function updateDataInDatabase(data, dispatch, getFirebase) {
    const idToken = await getFirebase().auth().currentUser.getIdToken();
    try {
        await axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/app/todo/data`, JSON.stringify(data), {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'firebase-idToken': idToken },
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        return err.message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`getIdToken` returns you a promise so you need to wait on it before using the values

```
const idToken = await getFirebase().auth().currentUser.getIdToken();
```